Отследить окончание закачки файла
После закачки файла над ним будут проводиться действия.
Есть ли возможность отслеживать уровень закачки файла? Либо состояние закачался или нет?
Использую вот такую функцию :
wget.download('https://...//update.exe')


так оно само отслеживает. Разве нет?

выводит шкалу только в консоль. а в программу можно ее вытянуть?

Можно requests использовать, завершение запроса и будет окончанием скачивания.

Можно немного модифицировать либу, и дергать от туда параметр загрузки.
